# Practical Perl solution to permutate through list for unique combinations

Tags: perl, permutation, combinations

Apologies if this looks like another problem - there are quite a lot of solutions and I didn't find what I'm looking for, but I may well have missed it. Also apologies if title isn't best description - not sure how else to word it.

I have five 'features' as strings, e.g.:

```
$height $width $depth $length $colour
```

I want to get all the different ***unique*** combinations starting with 5 and going down to 1 e.g.:

```
5: $height $width $depth $length $colour
4: $height $width $depth $length 
4: $height $width $depth $colour
4: $height $width $length $colour
4: $height $depth $length $colour
4: $width $depth $length $colour
...
and so on 
...
1: $height 
1: $width 
1: $depth 
1: $length 
1: $colour
```

I don't know if it makes a difference, but in code I plan to use `&&` and `!$string`, e.g.:

```
4: $height && $width && $depth && $length && !$colour 
4: $height && $width && $depth && !$length && $colour
4: $height && $width && !$depth && $length && $colour
4: $height && !$width && $depth && $length && $colour
4: !$height && $width && $depth && $length && $colour
and so on.
```

I was fine doing this by hand when I had 4 features, but with 5 it's too much! 
I thought putting the variables in a hash would may be good starting point, but as for the actual algorithm... Any help appreciated!

Edit: just realised it may not be clear, but I want to be able to 'query' each combination as they will be in if/elsif statements, so `if (h && w && !d ...)`

Comment: What's this for?  It smells like there might be a better way to solve the problem you're trying to solve with this.

Comment: there may well be... it's a project I'm working on and all the combinations correlate to a particular set of sql statements, with the idea being that some user has whatever features they choose to include affecting the results at the end. I now have to figure out the best way to do those haha

Comment: Why do you need to pre-calculate every possible permutation?

Comment: It is a development of what I had before, so seemed like the natural way to progress my code. I was actually hoping that I could combine it with the relevant dbi sql statements I have at some point. I have these statements in a `if (...) { $features = 'hwdl' }` format with the code merely being a shorter way to get the sql I want. I see that it is not necessary at this point, but it was before so I hadn't thought that far ahead!

Comment: I still want to know how to do it, though. Might as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encode a configuration as a 5 bit integer and just iterate from 0 to 2<sup>5</sup>-1.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1<<5; $i++) {

    my @output;
    push @output,  $i & 1  ? '$height' : '!$height';
    push @output,  $i & 2  ? '$width' : '!$width';
    push @output,  $i & 4  ? '$depth' : '!$depth';
    push @output,  $i & 8  ? '$length' : '!$length';
    push @output,  $i & 16 ? '$colour' : '!$colour';

    print join(' && ', @output), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I was about to write exactly that. Good tihng you posted it when you did! :)

Comment: what does the `$i & [num]` part do?

Comment: ok, finally tested this. it is doing the *opposite* of what I want! It is going up rather than down. So starts at 5 and then there are 10, and so on... HUGE list!

Comment: @bladpanthera - are you resetting `@output` in each iteration?

Comment: That was the problem indeed, I'd taken the `my @output` out of the loop. Great stuff! Nice work @mob

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Algorithm::Permute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aPermute)

```
use Algorithm::Permute; 
my @array = ($height, $width, $depth, $length, $colour); 
Algorithm::Permute::permute { print "@array" } @array;
```

This is also described in perlfaq: [How do I permute N elements of a list?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq4#How_do_I_permute_N_elements_of_a_list?)

Comment: +1 interesting answer, at the moment I can't install new modules so I can't test this, but thanks.

Comment: This is actually a perlfaq: http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perlfaq4.pod#How_do_I_permute_N_elements_of_a_list?

Comment: [But I can't use CPAN](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/) ... [Yes, even you can use CPAN](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828)

Comment: That doesn't include the partial permutations, though, does it?

Comment: @triplee As far as I know, the module can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You want unique combinations?  Try [Math::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Combinatorics/).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Math::Combinatorics qw(combine);

our @primary_qualities = qw(height width depth length colour);

for my $n (1 .. @primary_qualities) {
  say "@$_" for combine($n, @primary_qualities);
}
```

You'll have to handle the degenerate case (no height, no width, no depth, no length, no colour) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Algorithm::Permute`](http://search.cpan.org/~edpratomo/Algorithm-Permute-0.12/Permute.pm)

```
use Algorithm::Permute;

  my $props = [$height, $width, $depth, $length, $colour];



  foreach my $n ( 1.. scalar( @$props) ){
      my $p = new Algorithm::Permute($props, $n);
     #you can create r of n objects permutation generator, where r <= n
      while (@res = $p->next) {
        print join(", ", @res), "\n";
      }
  }
```